# How do you map fields to a differently named field with DRF serializers?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

If I have a `APIQuery` object, that gives me the following representation:

```
{
  'key': 'Foo',
  'field_1': 'John',
  'field_2': 'Doe',
}
```

And I am trying to store it with a model, like

```
class Person(models.Model):
  key = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
  first = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  last = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How do I properly setup a serializer, with the constraint that the keys in the `APIQuery` object are subject to change, e.g. `field_1` could become `field_17`. I know that without that last constraint I could just do

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  key = serializers.CharField()
  field_1 = serializers.CharField(source='first')
  field_2 = serializers.CharField(source='last')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SerializerMethodField` and define function `get_last_name`which will return last name.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   key = serializers.CharField()
   field_1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_first_name')
   field_2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_last_name')

   class Meta:
       model = "Person"
       fields = ('key','field_1','field_2')

   def get_first_name(self, obj):
       return obj.first       

   def get_last_name(self, obj):
       return obj.last
```